# Adding worker to Spark Standalone CDH5.3

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have a cloudera cdh5.3 quickstart running on a VM. I am having problems with running Spark. I have gone through those steps http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_ig_spark_configure.... and run the word exapmle and it worked. But when I go to the master (quickstart.cloudera:18080) it has no workers there the cores=0, memory=0... when I go to (quickstart.cloudera:18081) there is a worker. My question is how to add workers? And what should I enter in export STANDALONE_SPARK_MASTER_HOST?

This is the spark-env.sh:

```
#Change the following to specify a real cluster's Master host
export STANDALONE_SPARK_MASTER_HOST=worker-20150402201049-10.0.2.15-7078
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=$STANDALONE_SPARK_MASTER_HOST
### Let's run everything with JVM runtime, instead of Scala
export SPARK_LAUNCH_WITH_SCALA=0
export SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH=${SPARK_HOME}/lib
export SCALA_LIBRARY_PATH=${SPARK_HOME}/lib
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=18080
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
export SPARK_WORKER_PORT=7078
export SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT=18081
export SPARK_WORKER_DIR=/var/run/spark/work
export SPARK_LOG_DIR=/var/log/spark
export SPARK_PID_DIR='/var/run/spark/'
if [ -n "$HADOOP_HOME" ]; then
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/lib/native
fi
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-etc/hadoop/conf}
### Comment above 2 lines and uncomment the following if
### you want to run with scala version, that is included with the package
#export SCALA_HOME=${SCALA_HOME:-/usr/lib/spark/scala}
#export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin
```

Thank you

Comment: Is `worker-20150402201049-10.0.2.15-7078` really the master's host name? Sounds like the worker's name.

Comment: The hostname is: quickstart.cloudera and that is the workers name. I also tried quickstart.cloudera as Masters name but didn't work as well.

Comment: Yes I tried putting spark://10.0.2.15:7077 and spark://10.0.2.15:18080 but still I get: 
    URL: spark://10.0.2.15:7077
    Workers: 0
    Cores: 0 Total, 0 Used
    Memory: 0.0 B Total, 0.0 B Used
    Applications: 0 Running, 0 Completed
    Drivers: 0 Running, 0 Completed
    Status: ALIVE

Comment: This is Spark Master at spark://10.0.2.15:7077 and the worker's is spark://10.0.2.15:7078

Comment: I haven't tried that before and it WORKED.
Thank you very much Marius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `export STANDALONE_SPARK_MASTER_HOST=10.0.2.15` to your `spark-env.sh` so both master and worker agree on the same host address.